# Complete a multithreading parallelize process with k threads

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

`3sum` Problem is defined as
Given: A positive integer `k≤20`, a postive integer `n≤104`, and `k` arrays of size `n` containing integers from `−105` to `105`.

Return: `For each array A[1..n]`, output three different indices `1≤p<q<r≤n` such that `A[p]+A[q]+A[r]=0` if exist, and `"-1"` otherwise.

```
Sample Dataset
4 5
2 -3 4 10 5
8 -6 4 -2 -8
-5 2 3 2 -4
2 4 -5 6 8

Sample Output
-1
1 2 4
1 2 3
-1
```

However I want to speed up the code using threads, To do so I am applying python code

```
def TS(arr):
    original = arr[:]
    arr.sort()
    n = len(arr)        
    for i in xrange(n-2):
        a = arr[i]
        j = i+1
        k = n-1
        while j < k:
            b = arr[j]
            c = arr[k]
            if a + b + c == 0:
                return sorted([original.index(a)+1,original.index(b)+1,original.index(c)+1])
            elif a + b + c > 0:
                k = k - 1
            else:
                j = j +1
    return [-1]

with open("dataset.txt") as dataset:
   k = int(dataset.readline().split()[0]) 
   for i in xrange(k):
       aux = map(int, dataset.readline().split())
       results = TS(aux)
       print ' ' . join(map(str, results))
```

I was thinking on creating k threads, and a global array output, however do not know how to continue developing the idea

```
from threading import Thread

class thread_it(Thread):
    def __init__ (self,param):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.param = param
    def run(self):
        mutex.acquire()
        output.append(TS(aux))
        mutex.release() 


threads = []  #k threads
output = []   #global answer
mutex = thread.allocate_lock()
with open("dataset.txt") as dataset:
       k = int(dataset.readline().split()[0]) 
       for i in xrange(k):
           aux = map(int, dataset.readline().split())           
           current = thread_it(aux)
           threads.append(current)
           current.start()
           
       for t in threads:
           t.join()
```

What would be the correct way to get the `results = TS(aux)` inside a thread and then wait until all threads have finish and then `print ' ' . join(map(str,results))` for all of them?

## Update

Got this issue when running script from console
[image]

Comment: You can't speed up this code using threads; you'd need to use `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, like @Cyphase said, because of GIL, you cannot speed things up with `threading`. Every thread will run on the same core. Consider using `multiprocessing` to utilize multiple cores, `multiprocessing` has a very similar API as threading.

Second, even if we pretend GIL doesn't exist. Putting everything in a critical section protected by `mutex`, you are actually serializing all the threads. What you need to protect is access to `output`, so put the processing code out of critical section, to make them run concurrently:

```
def run(self):
    result = TS(aux)
    mutex.acquire()
    output.append(result)
    mutex.release()
```

But don't re-invent the wheel, python standard library provides a thread-safe Queue, use that:

```
try:
    import Queue as queue  # python2
except:
    import queue
output = queue.Queue()

def run(self):
    result = TS(self.param)
    output.append(result)
```

With multiprocessing, the final code looks something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
output = Queue()

class TSProcess(Process):
    def __init__ (self, param):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.param = param
    def run(self):
        result = TS(self.param)
        output.put(result)

processes = []  
with open("dataset.txt") as dataset:
       k = int(dataset.readline().split()[0]) 
       for i in xrange(k):
           aux = map(int, dataset.readline().split())           
           current = TSProcess(aux)
           processes.append(current)
           current.start()

       for p in processes:
           p.join()
       # process result with output.get()
```

Comment: I think you mean @Cyphase, not cMinor, and I think you mean GIL, not PIL :).

Comment: @Cyphase Acute symptom of sleep deprivation ;)

Comment: Oh, I understand :). You missed a 'PIL' by the way :P.

Comment: Ok, I understand however How would final code adding your code look like? How to call `run(self)` inside main loop `for i in xrange(k):` ?

Comment: @cMinor I added the final code, using `multiprocessing`.

Comment: I maybe wrong but when trying to process result with output.get I get empty result, what could I be missing?

Comment: There was a typo in the code I posted, corrected. But that should be irrelevant, I define `TS` to just return the arguments, the results are fine.

Comment: I keep on getting `in <module>
    current.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 280, in __init__
    to_child.close()
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`  I will accept your answer @NeoWang but could you please help me on this one?

Comment: @cMinor Others have met this problem when executing the script in REPL or a IDE. Have you tried running it from command line:`python script.py`?

Comment: @NeoWang Got same issues, I added a pincture of running it from console